# Unable to resolve values from spring boot application yaml files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

Hi I am haveing a spring boot rest based application . I have added a couple of properties related to elastic search in my application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml file . These properties are injected into my PerformanceReportingRepository class . however they are set to null .

so following is my yml definition .

```
# ===================================================================
# Standard Spring Boot properties.
# Full reference is available at:
# http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html
# ===================================================================

logging:
    level:
        ROOT: TRACE
        com.openmind.primecast: DEBUG
        io.github.jhipster: TRACE

spring:
    profiles:
        active: dev
        include: swagger
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: true
        livereload:
            enabled: false # we use gulp + BrowserSync for livereload
    jackson:
        serialization.indent_output: true
    data:
        cassandra:
            contactPoints: localhost
            protocolVersion: V4
            compression: LZ4
            keyspaceName: Openmind
    mail:
        host: localhost
        port: 25
        username:
        password:
        properties:
            mail:
                smtp:
                    auth: true
                    starttls.enable: true
    messages:
        cache-seconds: 1
    thymeleaf:
        cache: false
    http:
        multipart:
            maxFileSize: 150MB
            maxRequestSize: 150MB



# ===================================================================
# To enable SSL, generate a certificate using:
# keytool -genkey -alias primecast -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650
#
# You can also use Let's Encrypt:
# https://maximilian-boehm.com/hp2121/Create-a-Java-Keystore-JKS-from-Let-s-Encrypt-Certificates.htm
#
# Then, modify the server.ssl properties so your "server" configuration looks like:
#
# server:
#    port: 8443
#    ssl:
#        key-store: keystore.p12
#        key-store-password: <your-password>
#        key-store-type: PKCS12
#        key-alias: primecast
# ===================================================================
server:
    port: 8080

# ===================================================================
# JHipster specific properties
#
# Full reference is available at: http://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
# ===================================================================

jhipster:
    http:
        version: V_1_1 # To use HTTP/2 you will need SSL support (see above the "server.ssl" configuration)
    cache: # Cache configuration
        hazelcast: # Hazelcast distributed cache
            time-to-live-seconds: 3600
            backup-count: 1
            management-center: # Full reference is available at: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/management-center/3.9/manual/html/Deploying_and_Starting.html
                enabled: false
                update-interval: 3
                url: http://localhost:8180/mancenter
    # CORS is only enabled by default with the "dev" profile, so BrowserSync can access the API
    cors:
        allowed-origins: "*"
        allowed-methods: "*"
        allowed-headers: "*"
        exposed-headers: "Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count"
        allow-credentials: true
        max-age: 1800
    security:
        authentication:
            jwt:
                secret: my-secret-token-to-change-in-production
                # Token is valid 24 hours
                token-validity-in-seconds: 86400
                token-validity-in-seconds-for-remember-me: 2592000
    mail: # specific JHipster mail property, for standard properties see MailProperties
        from: primecast@localhost
        base-url: http://127.0.0.1:8080
    metrics: # DropWizard Metrics configuration, used by MetricsConfiguration
        jmx.enabled: true
        graphite: # Use the "graphite" Maven profile to have the Graphite dependencies
            enabled: false
            host: localhost
            port: 2003
            prefix: primecast
        prometheus: # Use the "prometheus" Maven profile to have the Prometheus dependencies
            enabled: false
            endpoint: /prometheusMetrics
        logs: # Reports Dropwizard metrics in the logs
            enabled: false
            report-frequency: 60 # in seconds
    logging:
        logstash: # Forward logs to logstash over a socket, used by LoggingConfiguration
            enabled: false
            host: localhost
            port: 5000
            queue-size: 512

google:
    accessToken: AIzaSyBasWNyK7ELbLlopD3anXrJCgtXUPRZYN8
    endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url

urlshortener:
    is.gd:
        endpoint: https://is.gd
    http:
        proxyEnabled: false
        proxyHost:
        proxyPort:

password:
    expiryInDays: 90
    historyCount: 3
    expiryEmailAlertInDays: 3
    policy: '^(?!.*(.)\1\1)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}.*$'

file:
   size: 5242880

elasticsearch:
    host: localhost
    port: 9200
```

and my repository class is

```
@Repository
public class PerformanceReportingRepository {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
    private Integer port;


    @Value("${file.size}")
    private long fileUploadSizeLimit;


    private RestHighLevelClient elasticSearchClient;


    public PerformanceReportingRepository() {
        System.out.println(this.fileUploadSizeLimit);
        this.elasticSearchClient = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port)));
    }


    public void setElasticSearchClient(RestHighLevelClient elasticSearchClient) {
        this.elasticSearchClient = elasticSearchClient;
    }
}
```

However the bean creation fails because host and port are not resolved from the yaml file.

I am sharing the project in https://github.com/prasanthmp500/mep.git 
please checkout the branch ENG-170-performance-reports

appreciate any help

thanks a lot

Comment: Remove `@Repository` and put `@Component`

Comment: that didnt work thank you